# how to search a "path" in the file path section using gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I am using Gerrit for a code review. I am trying to  to search using regex gto find all the reviews that contains a specific path in the file path section:
For example i have the following file in a review:
app/classes/orm/provider/filename.php

I want to be able to find all the reviews containing the following:
app/classes/orm/provider/
I have tried the following in the search field: file:^app/classes/orm/provider/(the scapes are not showing for "/")

Any help is appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: this is not git, this is gerrit. what you mean by git whatchanged?

Answer (score 6):

was able to solved using:
file:^app/classes/orm/provider/.*

Comment: where did you find this? I need to set multiple paths and dont know its syntax. example `path:^src/common/sensors/**/*.go|src/damn/origin/**/*.go` or will i do ``path:^src/common/sensors/**/*.go||src/damn/origin/**/*.go``